# How to get a particular image from media library in Windows Phone programmatically?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, get

I have a image name like sample.jpg, this picture was available in my Windows Phone media library.

How to get that picture via code from that name not using photochooser task.

If i use photochooser task it open the media library and select the particular image.

But i want directly get the particular image with help of this image name not open media library and all.

Is it possible.

We can get the name of the last or first element of the picture library

like

```
media.Pictures.First().Name.ToString()

                or

media.Pictures.Last().Name.ToString()
```

Likewise any property is there for get the particular image from that image name(`media.Pictures.contains("sample.jpg");`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a search criteria as a parameter for the `First` or `Last` method:

```
var picture = media.Pictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Contains("sample.jpg"));

if (picture != null)
{
    // Picture found
}
```

Comment: Thank you KooKiz, it's working fine. I have another question. How to put that image into image control.

Comment: Hi Kookiz i got answer from your answer, **GetImage()** method is there.                                                                    if (picture != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Picture found");
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());

                get_from.Source = image;
                
            }